# Hammer js: pinchend sometimes doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, interact.js

I'm using `pinchin`, `pinchout` and `pinchend`. If it's a long `pinchin` or `pinchout` the `pinchend` fires ok, but if it's a short `pinchin` or `pinchout` the `pinchend` doesn't fire. Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

```
gestos = new Hammer.Manager(document.body, {
    touchAction: "manipulation"
});
gestos.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinch'})); // If it isn't added, pinchout and pinchend never fires 
gestos.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinchin'}));
gestos.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinchout'}));
gestos.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinchend'}));
gestos.on("pinchin pinchout pinchend", function (e) { 
    if (e.type == "pinchin")
        interact("#mapa").resizable(false);
    else
        interact("#mapa").resizable(true);
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gestos.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinchcancel'}));
gestos.on("pinchin pinchout pinchend pinchcencel", function (e) { 
    if (e.type == "pinchin")
        interact("#mapa").resizable(false);
    else
        interact("#mapa").resizable(true);
    console.log(e.type);
});
//sometimes the device just recognize our move as pinchcancel when we actually want to fire pinchend event.
```

Comment: You should write an answer, not just supply a code snippet.

Comment: I think I clarified my point.just add pinchcancel response event